# Векторная анимация Android Studio, заливка, скорость анимации

Tags: android, анимация

Привет. Подскажите годную статью какую-нибудь, касающуюся векторной анимации (желательно с примерами). Полистал форумы, почитал, но пока не особо догнал. Делал приложение, нужно было сделать 2 цикличные анимации, но с возможностью изменения скорости этой самой анимации. Нарезал растровых картинок, одна картинка - один кадр, соответственно. Реализовал таким образом, что совсем неудобно, да и плохо для приложения и последующей работы с этой анимацией

```
public void startFrameAnimation() {        
    BitmapDrawable frame1 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.left0);
    BitmapDrawable frame2 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.left1);
    BitmapDrawable frame3 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.left2);
    BitmapDrawable frame4 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.left3);
    BitmapDrawable frame5 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.left4);
    BitmapDrawable frame6 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.left_full);


    mAnimationDrawable = new AnimationDrawable();

    mAnimationDrawable.setOneShot(false);
    mAnimationDrawable.addFrame(frame1, DURATION);
    mAnimationDrawable.addFrame(frame2, DURATION);
    mAnimationDrawable.addFrame(frame3, DURATION);
    mAnimationDrawable.addFrame(frame4, DURATION);
    mAnimationDrawable.addFrame(frame5, DURATION);
    mAnimationDrawable.addFrame(frame6, DURATION+250);


    manimLeft.setBackground(mAnimationDrawable);

    if (!mAnimationDrawable.isRunning()) {
        mAnimationDrawable.setVisible(true, true);

    }
}

public void startFrameAnimation2() {        
    BitmapDrawable frame1 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.right0);
    BitmapDrawable frame2 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.right1);
    BitmapDrawable frame3 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.right2);
    BitmapDrawable frame4 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.right3);
    BitmapDrawable frame5 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.right4);
    BitmapDrawable frame6 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.right_full);


    mAnimationDrawable2 = new AnimationDrawable();

    mAnimationDrawable2.setOneShot(false);
    mAnimationDrawable2.addFrame(frame1, DURATION);
    mAnimationDrawable2.addFrame(frame2, DURATION);
    mAnimationDrawable2.addFrame(frame3, DURATION);
    mAnimationDrawable2.addFrame(frame4, DURATION);
    mAnimationDrawable2.addFrame(frame5, DURATION);
    mAnimationDrawable2.addFrame(frame6, DURATION+250);


    manimRight.setBackground(mAnimationDrawable2);

    if (!mAnimationDrawable2.isRunning()) {
        mAnimationDrawable2.setVisible(true, true);

    }
}
```

Сейчас сделан один векторный рисунок, состоящий из нескольких секций. Эти самые секции должны заливаться по очереди в разные цвета. Вот собственно и вся анимация. Ну и вопрос: как я могу сделать эту анимацию, определить для какого фрейма какую секцию залить и как я могу управлять скоростью анимации? В принципе, я понимаю, что это все можно сделать в xml, но из кода я должен ускорять или замедлять эту анимацию. Какие способы реализации есть, ребят? Спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте через этот ресурс [https://shapeshifter.design/](https://shapeshifter.design/). Правда не уверен, что можно будет менять скорость анимации в рантайме.

Comment: @eugeneek спасибо, штука интересная. всё удобнее, чем ручками тыкать) а с рантаймом это да, что то думать буду

Comment: так в Android уже есть морф анимация для этого c API 21. Всмысле написать пример или что. Да кстати изменять скорость в рантайме, можно но коряво, подменой полностью, класса anim_vector. Возможно есть динамический способ, но что-т я не видел такого.